# Diacritics in a Pascal console APP?

Tags: console, console-application, pascal, diacritics, freepascal

I print messages with diacritics in my console application. I tried to set multiple encoding commonly used for my language (**CZECH**) but non of them is giving me the desired result. I tried UTF-8, Windows(CP1250), ISO 8859-2...

Is there a way how to force console to use some specific encoding?

Or at least where can I find which encoding does my console use?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Using Windows 7  - basic command line console ( cmd.exe )

Comment: What terminal do you use?

Comment: Please specify _at least_ whether you are on Windows, Linux or other

Comment: @Walter Tross Well Windows 7, but you could just guess that from the Windows encoding :D

Comment: let's avoid flames. Anyways, CP1250 does not imply Windows.

Comment: It does not, but I belive that "Windows(CP1250)" does, doesnt it ? :) (PS: Deleted the flames ;) )

Comment: no, it doesn't, because these CP<number> are Windows codepages, but are used in lots of non-Windows places

Comment: @Walter Tross I know, that is why I added the "Windows" before it - are there non-Windows places which store encoding specificly like "Windows...somecp"?

Comment: You can consider Windows the maker, and CP-<number>, or, equivalently, Windows-<number>, the model. Right now I'm on a Windows machine, but, e.g., LibreOffice (which is all but a Microsoft product) has in its select list of encodings "Eastern Europe(Windows-1250/WinLatin 2)"

Comment: That is very useful info, I will try to be more "informatic" nexttime, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the current codepage in `cmd.exe`:

```
chcp
```

To change the current codepage, e.g., to `CP-1250`:

```
chcp 1250
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, the Windows console uses the OEM encoding.  There are three  encodings for APIs in Windows OEM, ANSI and Unicode. CMD.exe when normally executed uses OEM.

UTF8 seems to be possible, but needs

1. starting the console with "cmd /u" (create a shortcut)
2. setting the codepage to chcp 65001
3. choosing a unicode capable font (e.g. Consolas 20) in the settings of the shortcut